# How do you stop displaying a div element (id) after a certain amount of time?

Tags: javascript, html

I have been coding a website, but I want a message to disappear/not display after a few seconds. I tried different code snippets but I cannot seem to plug them in properly with my code. Is there any way I could make it stop displaying after a certain amount of time?

```js
var done = "Done!";
document.getElementById("done").innerHTML = done;

var startTime = new Date().getTime();
var interval = setInterval(function() {
  if (new Date().getTime() - startTime > 2000) {
    clearInterval(interval);
    return;
  }
  done.getElementById.remove("done");
}, 2000);
```

```html
<h2 style="color:green;" id="greendisp">
  <span id="done"></span>
</h2>
```

Comment: What do you think `done.getElementById` is if `done` is a string? And instead of `setInterval` you could use `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `setTimeout`

```js
const done = "Done!";
document.getElementById("done").innerHTML = done;

setTimeout(() => {
  document.getElementById("done").remove()
}, 2000)
```

```html
<h2 style="color:green;" id="greendisp"><span id="done"></span></h2>
```

Comment: Thank you! I see my error now, because i did try this earlier except I declared done as a variable instead of constant. I appreciate it!

Comment: Thanks! I'm a new coder and I'm working on a website right now for some peers! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

This will use a timeout instead of an interval.

```js
// Element to remove
const targetId = 'done';
// Set HTML of element with id 'done' to 'Done!'
document.getElementById(targetId).innerHTML = "Done!";

// Set a Timeout which will call the function inside after 2000ms (2 seconds)
setTimeout(function () {
    // Remove the target element with id 'done'
    document.getElementById(targetId).remove();
}, 2000);
```

```html
<h2 style="color:green;" id="greendisp"><span id="done"></span></h2>
```